# datepicker selected value not getting submitted

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2

i am trying to submit to a action once user selects something in the struts jquery datepicker though the form is getting submitted to action the datepicker value is not getting set here is my code.

```
main.jsp
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <sj:head compressed="false"/>
<title><s:text name="title.search.main" /></title></head>
<body>
<s:form action="ProcessRoutes.action" id="processRoutesForm">
<s:url id="findDCs" value="/xxxDCs.action"/>
<sj:datepicker name="strRouteDate" id="strRouteDate"
value="%{getText('format.date', '',{routeDate})}"
cssClass="smallField"
onCompleteTopics="datepickerSelectedDate"/>
<sj:div id="findDCsDiv" href="%{findDCs}" listenTopics="datepickerSelectedDate">
  <sj:select id="dcSelect" name="selectedDc" list="%{#session.shipDCList}"
  listKey="number" listValue="name"
  headerKey="" headerValue="Select DC" onChangeTopics="dcSelectChanged"
  src="findRoutes.action">
  </sj:select>
 </sj:div>
</s:form></body></html>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="xxxDCs"    
    class="XXX.SearchMainAction"
    method="xxxDCs">
        <result name="input">/jsp/shipdcs.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/jsp/shipdcs.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

action class contains getter setter for strRouteDate whose datatype is string i also tried changing that to Date datatype.
where i am going wrong ,appreciate any help.

Comment: All we need to know is what is the format of the string being passed to struts2 and if you have made any efforts to change default date handling, there is no need for the JS at all.

Comment: no i have not changed anything,i checked post data with fiddler no data is getting passed to struts2 action class.

Comment: Well then this becomes a JS question... Why not use the jQuery UI datetime picker without those sj tags so you can just use the jQuery UI documentation. If you have issues you can ask the very responsive jQuery people and they will know what you are talking about, after you have a string which is trying to make its way to stuts2 I doubt you'll have an issue but if there is you can ask us (struts2 people).

Answer (score 0):

we need to add elementIds or formIds to the sj:div to get form values submitted